# Invalid syntax when setting variable

Tags: python-3

When setting variable c1, it shows invalid syntax error on c1

```
def project(k, n):
  h = 200
  L = 18
  M = 70
  da = 8
  xo = h - L
  g = 9.81
  V0 = m.sqrt(2 * g * L)
  W = M * g
  xss = -(W / k) + h - L
  wn = m.sqrt(k / M)
  dc = 2 * m.sqrt(k * M)
  c = (k * n) / wn
  ctotal = c + da
  dr = ctotal / dc
  wd = wn * m.sqrt(1 - dr**2)
  Td = (2 * m.pi / (wn * m.sqrt(1 - dr**2))
  c1 = xo - xss
  c2 = (V0 + dr * wn * (xo - xss)) / wd
  c11 = - dr * wn * c1 + c2 * wd
  c22 = - dr * wn * c2 - c1 * wd
  c111 = - dr * wn * c11 + c22 * wd
  c222 = - dr * wn * c22 - c11 * wd
  c1111 = - dr * wn * c111 + c222 * wd
  c2222 = - dr * wn * c222 - c111 * wd
  c5 = - dr * wn * c1111 + c2222 * wd
  c6 = - dr * wn * c2222 - c1111 * wd
  xRoot = Newton(Td / 4, Td / 2, velo, acc, 1.0e-9, dr, wn, t, c11, c22, wd, c111, c222)
  maxX = deflect(dr, wn, xRoot, c1, c2, wd) + Xss
  vRoot = Newton(0, Td / 8, acc, DAcc, 1.0e-9, dr, wn, t, c111, c222, wd, c1111, c2222)
  maxV = velo(dr, wn, vRoot, c11, c22, wd)
  aRoot = Newton(Td / 4, Td / 2, DAcc, D2Acc, 1.0e-9, dr, wn, t, c1111, c2222, wd, c5, c6)
  maxA = acc(dr, wn, aRoot, c111, c222, wd)
  return xRoot, maxX, vRoot, maxV, aRoot, maxA
```

Comment: I couldn't help noticing you broke the naming convention here. `c5` and `c6` should be named `c11111` and `c22222`, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

When a syntax error is reported, sometime the problem is in the line before.

```
Td = (2 * m.pi / (wn * m.sqrt(1 - dr**2))
c1 = xo - xss
```

Look a the first line, there is a missing closing bracket, or alternatively the first opening bracket is unnecessary.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Raspberry Pi.